# Laravel 4 adding numbers from foreach loop when count variable is supplied?

Tags: laravel-4

I am passing the array $cats to my laravel template view. It is a multidimensional array from a database transaction, containing category data. So it would contain data like:

```
$cat[0]['id'] = 1;
$cat[0]['name'] = 'First Category';
```

And so on. In my blade template I have the following code:

```
            {{ $i=0 }}
            @foreach($cats as $cat)

                    {{ $cat['name'] }}<br />

                {{ $i++ }}

            @endforeach
```

Which outputs:

```
0 First Category
1 Second Category
2 Third Category
```

Notice the numbers preceding the category name. Where are they coming from? Is this some clever Laravel trick? It seems that when you include a counter variable, they are automatically added. I can't find any mention of it anywhere, and I don't want them! How do I get rid of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You just need to use the plain php translation:

```
@foreach ($collection as $index => $element)
   {{$index}} - {{$element['name']}}
@endforeach
```

**EDIT:**

Note the `$index` will start from `0`, So it should be `{{ $index+1 }}`

Answer (score 11):

The `{{ }}` syntax in blade essentially means echo. You are echoing out `$i++` in each iteration of your loop. if you dont want this value to echo you should instead wrap in php tags. e.g.:

```
<?php $i=0 ?>

@foreach($cats as $cat)
    {{ $cat['name'] }}<br />
<?php $i++ ?>
@endforeach
```

As an additional note, if you choose to work in arrays then thats your call but unless you have a specific reason to do so I would encourage you to work with object syntax, eloquent collection objects in laravel can be iterated over just like arrays but give you a whole lot of extra sugar once you get used to it.

Comment: Oh right! OK, I see now. Thanks. Thanks also for the advice- do you have any links to where I can read about "eloquent collection objects"?

Comment: No problem - You're gonna love Laravel. Here is the obvious place for docs on eloquent collections http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections but this one is also a very good resource http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-collections

Comment: Awesome. Yes, I've actually been working my way through the Dayle Rees tutorial. I realise now that my initial question was incorrect, $cats is indeed already a collection object rather than a simple array, I just didn't realise it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($cats as $cat)
    {{ (isset($i))?$i++:($i = 0) }} - {{$cat['name']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your `$i` will always reset to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
<? php $i = 0 ?>
@foreach ( $variable_name as $value )
    {{ $ value }}<br />
< ? php $i++ ?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

if your $k is integer you can use {{ $k+1 }} or isn't integer you can use $loop->iteration
// for laravel version 4 and after

```
@foreach ($posts as $k => $post)
  {{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $post->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use a built in helper for this: `{{ $cat->incrementing }}`.

Comment: As far as I know `$cat->incrementing` would indicate if the IDs are auto-incrementing?