# how to fetch iterate number in blades foreach loop over collection

Tags: php, laravel, templates, foreach, laravel-blade

is there any way to fetch iterate number in blades foreach loop over collection ? I'm going to use it for selected drop down input default value . (i don't want to use "form model binding")

i try thesis and they does not work, maybe cause thesis for getting index value in foreach loop over objects :

`key($theArrayYouAreLoopingThrough)`

`{{ @index }}`

```
@foreach ($athletes as $key=>$athlete)
   {{ ++$key }}
@endforeach
```

and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 4 adding numbers from foreach loop when count variable is supplied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839771/laravel-4-adding-numbers-from-foreach-loop-when-count-variable-is-supplied)

Comment: i tried that answer before creating new question.  that is written solution for multi arrays , but in the collections than dose not work .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using 5.3 you can use [`$loop` variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable).

For example, to get current iteration, you can use inside `@foreach` or `@for` construction:

```
$loop->iteration
```

Comment: thank you dear Alexey for your attention again . i work with laravel 5.2 , is there any similar solution in laravel 5.2 ?

Comment: For 5.2 you can create variable and work with it by yourself or you can use this or similar package which adds `$loop` variable to Blade: https://github.com/RobinRadic/blade-extensions --- And here are examples of using `$loop` variable with this package: http://robin.radic.nl/blade-extensions/